# Yii Cdbmessage translation - CRUD

Tags: yii

In Yii framework, is there is any plugin/ module which do the CRUD operations for Cdbmessage source translations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of choise, you can try one of these:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/translate/ or http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ei18n/

Answer (score 0):

Also I can offer TsTranslation [TsTranslation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tstranslation/) extension.

It allow

- create and update dynamic content in different languages,
- get text using syntax `Yii::t($model, 'attribute')`,
- translate texts via Google Translate and more

DEMO and documentation: http://tstranslation.sundevelop.com/